# Некорректно отображается изменение прозрачности UIView

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, layout, opacity

Друзья, есть проблема с изменением прозрачности элементов UIView.
Меняю так: UIView.alpha = value. Если пытаюсь увеличивать видимость с шагом 0.01 - изображение "моргает". То есть, скажем, при значении 0.05 view может быть видно хуже, чем при 0.04. При постепенном увеличении видимости с шагом в 0.01 может быть ситуация, когда view видно лучше-лучше-хуже-лучше-хуже-лучше-лучше-лучше и т.д.
Вообще не понимаю в чем дело. Создал микро проект который это отражает - видно в симуляторе и на реальном девайсе (сразу грешил на экран). Если поможете/посмотрите проект - буду весьма благодарен.
Проект: https://goo.gl/vS2aLX

Comment: Обратил внимание, что если настроить анимацию появления UIView из alpha = 0.0 до alpha = 1.0 с продолжительностью 10 или 20 секунд, то UIView будет сильно "моргать". То есть то, о чем я говорю в оригинальном посте очень хорошо видно.

Comment: Для начала, сочетание цветов у Вас такое, что и 0.3 тяжело отличить от 0.6, не то что 0.04 от 0.05. Как Вы изменяете за 10 секунд с 0 до 1, приведите пример. P.S. не воспроизводится мигание: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wuOoSvU5i-Q

Comment: Вот видео с переходом от видимости 0 к видимости 1 за 20 секунд. Хорошо видно как моргает. Мне кажется я и на вашем видео вижу мерцания. https://youtu.be/in34amFvyOE

Comment: Проект https://goo.gl/0b4lRt

Answer (score 2):

Попробовал взять цвет color ricker'ом на каждых 10% альфы. - брал примерно в одном месте.

- 10 - #6664da
- 20 - #6766db
- 30 - #6966dd
- 40 - #6b67de
- 50 - #6c69df
- 60 - #6d6be1
- 70 - #6f6ce2
- 80 - #706de4
- 90 - #726ee6
- 100- #7470e7

Постоянно увеличивается.

При этом если например мерять каждый 0.01 между 0.1 и 0.2 то результаты вот такие

- 10 - #6664da
- 11 - #6664da
- 12 - #6664da
- 13 - #6665db
- 14 - #6665da
- 15 - #6665da
- 16 - #6665db
- 17 - #6665db
- 18 - #6765da
- 19 - #6765db
- 20 - #6765db

Как видно когда 13 переходит в 14 картинка действительно становится темнее, и подобный эффект наблюдается при переходите 17-18 где красный канал становится ярче, а синий темнее.

Предположу, что это артефакты при операциях с плавающей точкой, и программно никак это решить не удастся.

Возможно с проблемой удастся справиться используя sRGB добавленный в iOS10.